# Ansible: configure nginx role to use custom port read from variable

Tags: variables, ansible

I'm trying to create my custom role to install nginx by Ansible.

I defined this **defaults\main.yml**

```
---
defaults:
  user: nginx
  group: nginx
  version: "1.19.2-1"
  download_path: "/tmp/nginx-1.19.2-1"
  rpm: "/tmp/nginx-1.19.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64.rpm"
  directories:
    log: /var/log/nginx
    config: /etc/nginx
    custom_config: /etc/nginx/conf.d
    pid: /var/run
  config:
    - name: main
      content: |
        upstream backend {
          ip_hash;
          server localhost:9090;
          server 127.0.0.1:9090;
        }

        server {
          listen 9443 ssl;
          ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;
          location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
          }
        }
  server:
    port:
      listen:
        - 9443
```

And this is my tasks/main.yml

```
---
- set_fact:
    default_vars: "{{ defaults }}"
    host_vars: "{{ hostvars[ansible_host]['nginx'] | default({}) }}"
    install_nginx: true

- set_fact:
    combined_vars: "{{ default_vars | combine(host_vars, recursive=True) }}"

- name: Gather package facts
  package_facts:
    manager: auto

- set_fact:
    install_nginx: false
  when: "'nginx' in ansible_facts.packages"

- name: Install NginX
  yum:
    name: "{{ combined_vars.rpm }}"
   state: present
    disable_gpg_check: true
  become: true
  when:
    - install_nginx
    
- name: Make sure Ports Open
  community.general.seport:
    ports: "{{ port.listen }}"
    proto: tcp
    setype: http_port_t
    state: present
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "port"
  when: 'port.listen is defined'
  with_items: "{{ combined_vars.config.server }}"
  become: true
  ignore_errors: true
```

Now I receive the error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:9443 failed (13: Permission denied)
```

when I try to start nginx, this because my playbook skip the section **Make sure Ports Open** where I set to open **9443** port (read from config), and nginx don't start on not default port if you don't add this port (this is the command to run on OS to allow 9443 port: **semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp 9443**)

This is part of my log:

```
ok: [10.x.x.8] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "combined_vars": {
            "config": [
                {
                    "content": "upstream backend {\n  ip_hash;\n  server 10.x.x.:9090;\n  server 10.x.x.10:9090;\n}\n\nserver {\n  listen 9443 ssl;\n  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.crt;\n  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;\n  location / {\n    proxy_pass http://backend;\n  }\n}\n",
                    "name": "main"
                }
            ],
            "directories": {
                "config": "/etc/nginx",
                "custom_config": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                "log": "/var/log/nginx",
                "pid": "/var/run"
            },
            "download_path": "/tmp/nginx-1.19.2-1",
            "group": "nginx",
            "rpm": "/tmp/nginx-1.19.2-1.el7.ngx.x86_64.rpm",
            "server": {
                "port": {
                    "listen": [
                        9443
                    ]
                }
            },
            "user": "nginx",
            "version": "1.19.2-1"
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}


...
fatal: [10.x.x.8]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'port' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/opt/Developments/GitLab/harrisburg-infrastructure/roles/nginx/tasks/main.yml': line 95, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Make sure Ports Open Mod\n  ^ here\n"
}
```

Comment: How is the variable `port.listen` defined? The `seport` task should run to allow Nginx to bind to port 9443.

Comment: I update ```defaults/main.yml``` with port define, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:
**tasks/main.yml**

```
- name: Make sure Ports Open Mod
  community.general.seport:
    ports: "{{ combined_vars.server.port.listen }}"
    proto: tcp
    setype: http_port_t
    state: present
  loop_control:
    loop_var: "listen"
  when: 'combined_vars.server.port.listen is defined'
  with_items: "{{ combined_vars.server }}"
  become: true
  ignore_errors: true
```