# Only run Ansible seport when ports are not yet configured. Preferably not through shell or command module using semanage

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a role setup to install the iTOP application on LAMP/Rhel 8 with Ansible 2.9

I am trying to find a way to make the `seport` module only run when the needed ports are not yet configured. (make it idempotent)
I probably could use the `command` or `shell` module to run `semanage` and register a fact which i would use in a `when` condition.

What i was wondering is if there's a proper Ansible way to do this, without using `semanage` through `command` or `shell` module.

I had a look into the underneath link but its not what i'm looking for.
[Ansible: configure nginx role to use custom port read from variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191902/ansible-configure-nginx-role-to-use-custom-port-read-from-variable)

I did not find any examples or alternatives for this on Google.
In case anyone has any tips or hints, I would be most thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "proper" way of doing this in ansible. If you'll check code for seport module (as of today), you can see here:

https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/2f980e89fea8290cb57883d40e13c54a2e410259/plugins/modules/system/seport.py#L296

```py
    if state == 'present':
        result['changed'] = semanage_port_add(module, ports, proto, setype, do_reload)
    elif state == 'absent':
        result['changed'] = semanage_port_del(module, ports, proto, setype, do_reload)
    else:
        module.fail_json(msg='Invalid value of argument "state": {0}'.format(state))
```

So this module is certainly not idempotent, since it will return `changed` every time. You may try creating an issue, and someone might fix it

It seems that `semanage` cli is not idempotent too, `semanage port --add` will throw `ValueError: Port PROTO/PORT already defined`, and will take a lot of time. You have multiple options:

1. reimplement part of seport module with shell, but define changed criteria:

```
    - name: semanage add port
      shell: LANG=C semanage port --add -t zookeeper_election_port_t -p tcp 38888
      register: result
      failed_when: result.rc != 0 and "already defined" not in result.stderr
      changed_when:
        - result.rc == 0
```

2. Parse output of `semanage port -l | tr -s ' ' | grep 'port_type'` and match it with your condition, then call seport module

At first i wanted to point that 1st variant is kinda slow due to semanage implementation, but due to connection overhead it might be negligible difference in your case

Comment: Thank you, for your input. I had a solution similar to your second option but your first solution is far more efficient, i think.